# How to implode array data from index 2

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have array data like this :

```
$word[0]="search";
$word[1]="journal";
$word[2]="information";
$word[3]="system";
```

If I make PHP code like this :

$output=implode(" ",$word);

The output (implode result) is a combination of word ("search journal information system"). If I want to implode from index 2 so the result="information system". How the solution this problem?

Comment: Logic behind to where you cut string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try,

echo join(' ', array_slice($word, 2, 2));

// information system

Answer (score 3):

> Using array_slice() function get last two element and after implode this array

```
<?php
 $word[0]="search";
 $word[1]="journal";
 $word[2]="information";
 $word[3]="system";
 $word=array_slice($word, -2, 2, true);
 $output=implode(" ",$word);
 echo $output; //information system
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass whole array in  [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), 
As per guideline of implode function we can not pass index of array in so we have to modify array here.

you can use [array slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)  function for that:

```
<?php
$word[0]="search";
$word[1]="journal";
$word[2]="information";
$word[3]="system";
echo $secondnames = implode(" ",array_slice($word,2));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$word[0]="search";
$word[1]="journal";
$word[2]="information";
$word[3]="system";

echo implode(array($word[2], $word[3]), " ");
```